# Find a function $f(x)$ such that$\int_0^txf(x)f(\sqrt{t^2-x^2})dx=\sin(t^2)$

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, integral-equations

I am looking for a function that satisfies the integral equation $\int_0^txf(x)f(\sqrt{t^2-x^2})dx=\sin(t^2)$.  It's some sort of convolution.

If we denote the above equation by $ f(t)*f(t)=\sin(t^2)$ I was also able to show that $f(t)*(2\cos(t^2))=t^2f(t).$

The definition of $ f(t)*g(t)=\int_0^txf(x)g(\sqrt{t^2-x^2})dx$.

I also got $f(t)*\dfrac{f'(t)}{t}+f(0)f(t)=2\cos(t^2)$ through differentiation ($t>0$). That's all.

Comment: When do you need it by?  Should we gift-wrap it or will you use it on the go?  What attempts have you made up to this point to find such a function?

Comment: What's your motivation for finding such a function?

Comment: @abiessu he's asking a mathematical question on a mathematical forum.   What's the issue?  You can help or not, but your comment is uncalled for.

Comment: thank you @AmateurMathGuy

Comment: For this you first need $\cos(x^2)=\cos(t^2-x^2)$ or $x^2=t^2-x^2+2k\pi$

Comment: @AmateurMathGuy I think the point he is trying to make is that on the guide for how to ask a good question, it is important to illustrate any attempts made, any thoughts, or just something to show that one has put even a modicum of effort. This allows people to help better.

Comment: @HarryAlli A valid point.  Yet it's a guideline not a requirement.

Comment: @HarryAlli what if they have no idea where to even begin?

Comment: $f(\sqrt{t^2-x^2})=\cos(x^2)/f(x)$ is independent of $t$.

Comment: @yusuf what have you tried?

Comment: @YusufGurtas Perhaps you should modify your question to be about the integral equation instead. Than your initial question would count as an attempt and everyone's happy.

Comment: Can you also prove that the integral equation is equivalent to $f(t) * f(t) = \sin(t^2)$? If that's true then it can be solved using the Fourier/Laplace transform

Comment: @AmateurMathGuy: I threw in some cheeky comments at the beginning as a reminder that it's really helpful to include all the information that's available, and because the question as originally posed almost sounded to me like an order for coffee...  Also, there was no actual question posed, but rather there was a statement "I need this thing that has these properties..."

Comment: @abiessu I hear you and I don't blame you even though your first comment was a little unexpected. The reason I put the question out there in that form is I really thought that it would be an easy algebraic manipulation rather than solving an integral equation. I did not succeed and I thought someone else could just point out what I am failing to see in few moments (and give the answer to me on the go). Anyway, after taking another derivative and substituting all I know into that equation I was able to convert it to $ty′′+y′+4t^3y=0$ and Maple says the solution is BesselJ$(0,t^2)$.Thank you all

Answer (score 2):

$$\int_0^t f(x)f(\sqrt{t^2-x^2})xdx=\sin(t^2)$$
HINT :

Let $\quad f(x)=g(x^2)$
$$\int_0^t g(x^2)g(t^2-x^2)\frac{d(x^2)}{2}=\sin(t^2)$$
Let $\quad\begin{cases} x^2=X \\t^2=T\end{cases}$
$$\int_0^{\sqrt{T}} g(X)g(T-X)dX=2\sin(T)$$

Answer (score 2):

Using the hint

$\int_0^t g(X)g(t^2-X)dX=2\sin(t^2)$ we can write $\mathcal{L} \left \{ g(t^2) *g(t^2) \right\}= \mathcal{L} \left \{  2\sin(t^2 ) \right \}$.

Let $T=t^2$ and $ G(s)=\mathcal{L}\{g(T)\}$. Then  $ G(s)G(s)=\mathcal{L} \left \{  2\sin(T ) \right \}=\dfrac{2}{s^2+1}$.

Therefore $ G(s) =\dfrac{ \sqrt{2}}{\sqrt{s^2+1}} $ and $g(T)=\sqrt{2}\mathcal{L}^{-1} \left \{ \dfrac{1}{\sqrt{s^2+1}} \right \}=\sqrt{2}J_0(T) $.

Thus the answer is $f(t)=g(t^2)=\sqrt{2}J_0(t^2).$